# Lambda Aggregate Expression C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have following object model

```
class ObjectModel
{
    int id;
    string Name;
}
```

I need to concatenate the names from List of ObjectModel

I have used this lambda expression:

```
List<ObjectModel> objList = some method which returns the list
objList.Aggregate((a, b) => a.Name + " " + b.Name);
```

but I am getting an error

> Cannot implicitly convert string to ObjectModel

I need to use only lambda expression

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var accum = string.Join(" ", objList.Select(o => o.Name));
```

or stay with Aggregate like so:

```
var acc2 = objList.Aggregate("", (acc,item) => acc += " " + item).Trim();
```

The reason you get an conver exceptions is that your version needs an output of ObjectModel.

You are using this overload:

```
public static TSource Aggregate<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TSource, TSource> func
)
```

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx

I am using

```
public static TAccumulate Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,                                // ""
    Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func     // (acc,item) => string
)
```

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx

You return the same type as the IEnumeration has, I am free to return whatever type my 2nd Func does

Answer (score 1):

Try like this;

```
var names = objList.Select(x => x.Name).Aggregate((a, b) => a + " " + b);
```

`Aggregate` expects type of `ObjectModel` expression, you should `select` string `Name` variable first.